# How to make a bday counter in r to exit a while loop after 5 of the same bdays occur

Tags: r

How do I make a while loop to find make a bday counter to stop the while loop after 5 of the same days are done. (numbers 1 to 365)

```
n_people <- 0 # people counter, start at zero
bday_list <- rep(0, 365) # bday counter, each day starts with count = 0
bday_list
new_person <-sample(1:2, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
bday_list[new_person]
table[bday_list]
new_person
# no defined end to this problem/task!
while (n_people != 365) {
  # talk to my first person, increment counter
  n_people <- n_people + 1
  n_person <- sample(1:365, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What is `bday_list`? What is `new_person` ?

Comment: You don't need `replace=TRUE` with a sample of size 1. Adding a `break` may help you. Maybe `duplicated` with `sum`.

Comment: bday_list is everyday of the year. new_person is sampling a new person each day. then the count goes up as well. the new_person before the while loop doesn't matter

Comment: I also think that the while goes like this while(any(bday_list)!= 5)

Comment: How Would I put the exit condition in the while loop. I used an if any(bday_list) == 5 then I broke it but I don't know how I would do that in the while condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can update the `bday_list` vector based on its position and stop when any of the value in the vector reaches to 5.

```
bday_list <- rep(0, 365)
counter <- 0

while (all(bday_list < 5)) {
  n_person <- sample(1:365, size = 1)
  bday_list[n_person] <- bday_list[n_person] + 1
  counter <- counter + 1
}

cat('\nThe while loop exited after ', counter, ' iterations and the number is',
    which(bday_list == 5))

#The while loop exited after  332  iterations and the number is 119
```